# necklace layout string(node) text insertion

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

How to insert node(arrow) text in the graph of simple necklace layout?

my code:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth, every node/.style={rectangle,rectangle split, rectangle split parts=2,rectangle split part fill={red!30,white!20}, draw, minimum size=0.75cm}, node sep=3cm]
\graph [simple necklace layout]
    {

        Start,Hangup,Cancel Sms,Init1,Idle,SendSms1,TestModem,SendSms2,SendSms3;
  Start->Init1-> Idle;3 ->[xshift=3pt,yshift=-2pt]1 -> 2;
  3 -> 5 -> 6 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=-2pt]5, 5 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=2pt] 4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt] 6;

    };


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advace

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean, do you want to add text along the arrows?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Yes, that's what I want :)

Comment: And one more thing, why some arrows lose their tips, if I everywhere declared that it is ->, not --?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the syntax from the `quotes` library to do that.  For example, `a ->["some text"] b` will add *some text* next to the arrow. You can add options to that label by writing them immediately after the quote, e.g. `a ->["some text" {red,draw}] b`. I think you need the braces if there is more than one option.

Note that instead of redefining `every node` I made a style `mynode` and said `nodes={mynode}` in the `\graph` option. Otherwise, the labels for the arrows would be affected as well.

The arrow tips are all there, but they are covered by the lower part of the `rectangle split` nodes. Modify the filling to `rectangle split part fill={none,none}` and you'll see that. I don't know how to fix that at the moment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quotes,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}
\usegdlibrary{circular}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  >=Stealth,
  mynode/.style={
     rectangle,
     rectangle split,
     rectangle split parts=2,
     rectangle split part fill={red!30,white!20},
     draw, 
     minimum size=0.75cm},
  node sep=1cm]
\graph [
  simple necklace layout,nodes={mynode},
]
    {
     Start,
     Hangup,
     Cancel Sms,
     Init1,
     Idle,
     SendSms1,
     TestModem,
     SendSms2,
     SendSms3;
     Start->["Some text" {sloped,pos=0.6}]
        Init1->["relax" {sloped,below}]
        Idle;
     3 ->[xshift=3pt,yshift=-2pt]
        1 -> 2;
     3 -> 
         5 -> 
         6 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=-2pt] 
         4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=-2pt] 5; 
     5 ->[xshift=-1pt,yshift=2pt]
         4 ->[xshift=1pt,yshift=2pt,"abc"]
         6;
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```