# TikZ: wrong edge between split rectangles in graphs

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, node-connections

Consider the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,shapes.multipart}
    \usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz[every node/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw}]{
  \graph[tree layout,grow=0] {
    a/a\nodepart{two}1;
    b/b\nodepart{two}2;
    c/c\nodepart{two}3;
    a -- {b, c};
  };
}
\end{document}
```

The result (with PGF 3.0.1) is:

[image: graph with multipart nodes and wrong connections]

There is an incorrect edge in the sense that the line corresponding to `a -- c` does not stop at the edge of node `a`. Is this a bug or intended? How could I work around it?

Comment: Same problem pops up in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302393/necklace-layout-stringnode-text-insertion/302794#302794 I think, I'd be interested in seeing a solution myself.

Comment: It looks like a bug to me, but I don't seem to have permission anymore to add tickets to the PGF sourceforge bug tracker :-(.

Comment: Not related but you could be interested in: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42114/why-should-the-minimal-class-be-avoided and [standalone](http://ctan.org/pkg/standalone)

Comment: If you could specify an undrawn edge with a tree layout, you could work around it, but it seems you can't....

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be, because the boxes are transparent. I tried this:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing,shapes.multipart}
    \usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz[every node/.style={rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw, fill=white}]{
  \graph[tree layout,grow=0] {
    a/a\nodepart{two}1;
    b/b\nodepart{two}2;
    c/c\nodepart{two}3;
    a -- {b, c};
  };
}
\end{document}
```

[image]